# How to completely remove Jenkins from Windows 10

Tags: jenkins

I have been playing with Jenkins, but now I cannot log in at all, I just get

```
 Problem accessing /j_acegi_security_check. Reason:

No valid crumb was included in the request
```

No suggestions I have seen seems to fix it. So I want to uninstall and start again.

I have tried to uninstall, but when I reinstall, I still see my projects etc, and the I just keep getting the same above error.

I want to completely remove it so I can start again, as now I cannot use it at all.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually simple.

After running the uninstall, I just had to manually delete the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins` folder.

It seems to use this as the Jenkins data folder as well (as opposed to on mac where there is a `.jenkins` under the user home folder)

Comment: just check if Jenkin folder is there after uninstall.. if yes delete it C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\